# Property type not supported in Livewire error while using paginate() method

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, pagination, laravel-livewire

What I am trying show paginate links under a laravel livewire table. Now I am using get() method to display data and changed to paginate() to display only two results in the first page. Livewire components are included in the view of resources\views\product.blade.php. I get the specific error highlighting the line of code where I have included livewire component : @livewire('product.show', ['items' => $items]).

It works fine when I'm trying to use get method. But when I change to paginate method it displays the error **Property type not supported in Livewire for property...**.

app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php

```
...
public function index()
    {
        $items = Category::all();
        return view('product', compact('items'));

    }
...
```

resources\views\product.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">

                    @livewire('product.show', ['items' => $items])


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Livewire Components**

- app\Livewire\Product\Show.php

```
namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\this;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

use App\Models\Product;

class Show extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $products, $items, $name, $unit, $category,$price,$percentage,$discount,$start_date,$end_date,$tax_percentage,$tax_amount,$net_price,$stock_quantity;
    public $listMode = true;
    public $updateMode = false;
    public $selectedCategories = [];

    public $sortBy = 'name';
    public $sortDirection = 'asc';

    public function render()
    {
        //$this->items = Category::all();

        $this->products = Product::query()
        ->orderBy($this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection)
        ->paginate(2);
        return view('livewire.product.show');

    }
```

- resources\views\livewire\product\show.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-success" wire:click="create"> Create New Product</a>
        @if($listMode)
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th wire:click="sortByField('name')" style="cursor: pointer;">Name <i class="fa-solid fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th wire:click="sortByField('price')" style="cursor: pointer;">Price <i class="fa-solid fa-sort"></i> </th>
                <th>Discount Percentage</th>
                <th>Tax Percentage</th>
                <th>Net Price</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($products as $product)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $product->product_id }}</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->unit }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->categories->pluck('name')->implode(', ') }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->percentage }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->tax_percentage }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->net_price }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>

        @else
                @if($updateMode)
                @include('livewire.product.update')
                @else
                    @include('livewire.product.create')
                @endif
        @endif

{{ $products->links() }}

    </div>

</div>
```

Pls note: I have already tried to mount the $items = Category::all(); value in the livewire component. But still it displays the same error.

Comment: Which Livewire version you are using? 2 or 3

Answer (score 1):

In official docs give the best example of how pagination is working.
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/pagination

> Avoid using the `public $post` property for the pagination

It will work well with pass variables in the `view()` function

Your component

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class ListPost extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.list-post', [
            'posts' => Post::paginate(10),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Your component view file

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <ol>
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <li>{{ $post->title }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ol>
    </div>
 
    {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

The output will display like this.
[image: Livewire 3 Pagination view for posts]

Moreover, you can review the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/825) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('show-products', [
        'products' => Product::paginate(10),
    ]);
```

**use this format to return the products in your case.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).